# SpecRun+Nunit > Adding new feature file to project causing generating plugin not found error cs1029

Tags: specflow

This happens to me everytime! Have hooks setup and other feature files in the project.

I click on feature folder - add item (SpecFlow Feature File)
Name it and alter the gherkin syntax.
Right click Generate definition and add to steps folder
I delete VS Bin folder and Rebuild Solution.
I will then get the plugin error code CS1029 - no matter what I do I cannot prevent this error from popping up!

Answer (score 0):

Figured out why I would get the error of needing to regenerate feature files then wind up with a compilation error of SpecRun could not find plugin.

The project I had grabbed did not have up to date NuGet Packages! If you have **SpecRun+Nunit** as the **UniteTestprovider** - (I am on VS 2015, with extension Specflow for Visual Studio 2015 installed). Be sure the Nuget package for SpecRun is updated to the latest Stable version.

Your app config can have plugin [add name="SpecRun"] (Found some post mentioning to delete this, you do not)

You do not need to delete the bin folder and reopen vs. Just make sure Nuget packages for SpecRun is the latest.